# Updating profile information with meteor github package

Tags: meteor

Currently, using the Meteor github-accounts package a user is populated in the users table on creation. However, lets say a user changes their name on github, that doesn't ever get reflected on our site. Is there anyway to update a user in meteor to reflect those changes?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* update his / her profile after successful authentication with following code:

```js
    var accessToken = user.services.github.accessToken,
        result,
        profile;
    result = Meteor.http.get("https://api.github.com/user", {
        params: {
            access_token: accessToken
        }
    });
    if (result.error)
        throw result.error;

    profile = _.pick(result.data,
        "login",
        "name",
        "avatar_url",
        "url",
        "company",
        "blog",
        "location",
        "email",
        "bio",
        "html_url");

    user.profile = profile;
```